# PHP array unique by column

Tags: php

How to filter an array to give unique elements according to one or more columns. Example:

```
array(
    array('name'=>'toto', 'type'=>'1', 'type2'=> '2')
    array('name'=>'tata', 'type'=>'1', 'type2'=> '3')
    array('name'=>'titi', 'type'=>'1', 'type2'=> '2')
    array('name'=>'tutu', 'type'=>'2', 'type2'=> '4')
    array('name'=>'tete', 'type'=>'3', 'type2'=> '2')
)
```

If we choose type and type2 as the unique column. The result of the algorithm should gives

```
array(
    array('name'=>'toto', 'type'=>'1', 'type2'=> '2')
    array('name'=>'tata', 'type'=>'1', 'type2'=> '3')
    array('name'=>'tutu', 'type'=>'2', 'type2'=> '4')
    array('name'=>'tete', 'type'=>'3', 'type2'=> '2')
)
```

I can think of an algorithm by hashing the type concatenate with type2, store in a table and using isset to find the existence. But I'm not sure that's the best algorithm.

Comment: How does your algorithm decide which of `titi` or `toto` to discard?

Comment: You need to get unique values according to 'type2'?How to decide titi or toto is needed?

Comment: why not just do this in a database with unique column constraints?

Comment: @KevinBrydon Let's just say by default we take the first found array. In this case is `toto` array. Or if possible I want also a version that take the last found array. @Jakub: in my case, the data doesn't necessary come from a dump of SQL

Comment: Can anyone provide an answer here that does not use `foreach` and assignment, but is instead based on a map/filter/reduce implementation using PHP's array functions?

Comment: @NicholasShanks array filter does the same job all you need to do is return true/false if the condition is met

Comment: @ThanhTrung Actually I realised after posting that comment that I could achieve what I was looking for by sorting my array beforehand then using the third argument to `array_column` — for rows that share a value in the `key` column, the final row wins, so just sort with that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is

```
$data = array(
    array('name'=>'toto', 'type'=>'1', 'type2'=> '2'),
    array('name'=>'tata', 'type'=>'1', 'type2'=> '3'),
    array('name'=>'titi', 'type'=>'1', 'type2'=> '2'),
    array('name'=>'tutu', 'type'=>'2', 'type2'=> '4'),
    array('name'=>'tete', 'type'=>'3', 'type2'=> '2')
);


$tmp = array();
foreach($data as $v) {
    $id = $v['type'] . "|" . $v['type2'];
    isset($tmp[$id]) or $tmp[$id] = $v;
}
print_r(array_values($tmp));
```

Comment: Same as above, this only check for uniqueness of `type2`, I also want a comparison with `type` too

Comment: Your version only works in this special case... If I add `array('name'=>'tete', 'type'=>'3', 'type2'=> '2')` it's not gonna work...

Comment: Your solution is what I said in my post : `I can think of an algorithm by hashing the type concatenate with type2, store in a table and using isset to find the existence. But I'm not sure that's the best algorithm.` Actually, it would better if you hash your `$id` with md5()

Comment: I don't have failed test. I think you solution is the best so far. md5 is not necessary and it costs performance. The key of an array has no limitation in size. So what about keeping the last seen array? Could you give a 2nd version that will keep the and remove the 1st?

Comment: Keep it simple .... alternatives would be to use `array_reduce` might not be as readable or faster ....

Comment: `'type'=>'11', 'type2'=> '3'` can't be equivalent to `'type'=>'1', 'type2'=> '13'`?

Comment: Array reduce seems hard to use. I want to use the least function call as possible. @tassoevan No

Comment: @ThanhTrung `$v['type']. $v['type2'] == '11' . '3' == '1' . '13'`, no?

Answer (score 2):

```
$keys = array('type', 'type2');
$filtered = array();

foreach ($array as $elem) {
    $compKey = join('|', array_intersect_key($elem, array_flip($keys)));
    $filtered[$compKey] = $elem;
}

// optionally: $filtered = array_values($filtered);
```

Comment: Although generates the example result array, it only uses 'type2' as criteria, and OP required uniqueness based in 'type' column too.

Comment: Maybe true. The question is a bit too vague how exactly the algorithm should behave. I just read it as "choose one or the other".

Comment: Both type and type2 are required, sorry. Unique column is easy, I wouldn't ask...

Comment: @Thanh Then joining all values of all keys by some separator and use it as composite key should do the trick. Updated answer.

Comment: @deceze Result found will be : `titi, tata, tutu, tete`. Which is good enough for me. One small problem is that `titi` position is changed. Having `titi` after `tata` is perfect because we keep the order. Or is possible to replace `titi` with `toto` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array(
    array('name'=>'toto', 'type'=>'1', 'type2'=> '2'),
    array('name'=>'tata', 'type'=>'1', 'type2'=> '3'),
    array('name'=>'titi', 'type'=>'1', 'type2'=> '2'),
    array('name'=>'tutu', 'type'=>'2', 'type2'=> '4')
);

$filtered = array(); // resulting array
$combinations = array(); // combinations of 'type' and 'type2' values

foreach ( $arr as $elem ) {

    $comb = array($elem['type'], $elem['type2']);

    if ( !in_array($comb, $combinations) ) { // new combination
        $combinations[] = $comb;
        $filtered[] = $elem;
    }
}
```

Comment: This one works too. But same as above, `in_array` is overkill

Answer (score 1):

Updated to support key combinations

```
<?php

$array=array(
    array('name'=>'toto', 'type'=>'1', 'type2'=> '2'),
    array('name'=>'tata', 'type'=>'1', 'type2'=> '3'),
    array('name'=>'titi', 'type'=>'1', 'type2'=> '2'),
    array('name'=>'tutu', 'type'=>'2', 'type2'=> '4'),
);

function filter($key,$array){
    $filtered=array();
    $used=array();
    foreach ($array as $e){
        $v=array();
        foreach ($key as $k) $v[]=$e[$k];
        if (!in_array($v,$used)){
            $used[]=$v;
            $filtered[]=$e;
        }
    }
    return $filtered;
}

$filtered=filter(array('type2','type'),$array);
```

Comment: Which it is supposed to do when filtering on 'type'. Filtering on 'type2' will remove 'titi'. Second run, filtering on 'type' will remove tata.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't give the same result I want. The unique constraint is a couple (type, type2) not just one or another

Comment: Thanks, it worked. One problem is performance. Using in_array is overkill when you have 10k line of record for example. Try to use less function call as possible. The number of loop is `nb_field_unique * array_size²`

Comment: Now you want optimized as well? :-)

The solutions using keys will be faster then, since the keys are hashtables and thus O(1).

Answer (score 0):

What about this way?

Result array is not the same as that of the author. But still valid for the condition:

> ...filter an array to give unique elements according to one or more
> columns.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

$input = [
    ['name' => 'toto', 'type' => '1', 'type2' => '2'],
    ['name' => 'tata', 'type' => '1', 'type2' => '3'],
    ['name' => 'titi', 'type' => '1', 'type2' => '2'],
    ['name' => 'tutu', 'type' => '2', 'type2' => '4'],
    ['name' => 'tete', 'type' => '3', 'type2' => '2'],
];

$keys = array_map(
    static fn(string $key, string $value) => "$key:$value",
    array_column($input, 'type'), array_column($input, 'type2'));

$result = array_values(array_combine($keys, array_values($input)));

$expect = [
    ['name' => 'titi', 'type' => '1', 'type2' => '2'],
    ['name' => 'tata', 'type' => '1', 'type2' => '3'],
    ['name' => 'tutu', 'type' => '2', 'type2' => '4'],
    ['name' => 'tete', 'type' => '3', 'type2' => '2'],
];

assert($result === $expect); // true
```